# Google Cloud Speech to Text Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method build()Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;

Tags: java, android, google-speech-api, protobuf-java

I'm using Google Cloud Speech to text. For some reason, It works only the first time. After that, this error keeps appearing. I'm stuck.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   build()Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; in class
>   Lcom/google/cloud/speech/v1/RecognitionConfig$Builder; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig$Builder'

**build.gradle module app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf' 
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

ext {
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0' }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.android.com.colconvert"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    } }

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    } }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    // gRPC
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    // implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api.grpc', name: 'grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1', version: '0.1.13'
    // OAuth2 for Google API
    implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' 
}
```

Comment: Please post your dependencies in the `build.gradle` file. Please comment here after updating your post, so that I can take a look at it again. :)

Comment: @ReazMurshed I updated my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the version that you are using. I would recommend using the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.grpc/grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1) like the following.

```
implementation group: 'com.google.api.grpc', name: 'grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1', version: '1.10.0'
```

Hope that helps!